# Compass needle deflected when near off smartphone

Tags: shutdown

It puzzles me that a compass needle is deflected when I bring it near (~ 2 cm above the screen) my turned off Android smartphone, which can only mean there is still a electric current inside it. Surprisingly, the deflection is the same with the phone turned on. What may be the reason behind it?

I could yet not verify whether the same happens with other mobile phones.

Comment: It was quite hard deciding the appropriate StackExchange site for this question. I hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smartphones and tablets have magnets.

Speakers & microphones have magnets needed to operate.
There is a magnet for the vibration motor.

There may be magnets used to align wireless charging points.

See this video about magnetic paper which shows some examples of where magnets placed within electronic devices:

[Physics Girl - How Magnet Paper Works feat. MKBHD](https://youtu.be/HodWkE0G28M)

Comment: Of course! I forgot about the other obvious reason for a magnetic field: a magnet